# How to make sure the user enters a least one value Python

Tags: python

I am wondering about how I can make sure the user enters at least one letter or number as an input. With my code if they enter a blank space it accepts it, but I want to be able to make it so they at least enter one thing.

With this code:

```
s = input("Please enter a sentence")

print("Your sentence is",s)
```

It allows this:

```
Please enter a sentence

Your sentence is
```

I have entered a blank space and it has allowed it. Any idea on how to make sure they enter at least one letter or number?

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can add `while` loop like this:

```
s = ""

while not s.strip():
    s = input("Please enter a sentence")

print("Your sentence is",s)
```

Comment: To avoid repeating the `input` you could just do `s = ""` outside the loop.

Comment: Good point there...